# why is spark fast as compared to other data analytics tools like R, python etc

Tags: apache-spark

I am looking for a quick answer to a very basic question related to Spark. I really don't understand how spark works and why is fast?

Question is, "Is spark fast because it divides a job into say 100 parts and run all parts at the same time or is it fast because its processing speed is superfast (in this case I am assuming that spark does not divide a job into 100 parts but just processes the job at one go) or it can do both?"

Another question, "Is spark a cluster of different physical machines or a cluster of different environments on a single machines"? 
Thanks,

Comment: You're question is really broad. Try searching for one of many spark introductions. In short spark can be better than R or python because it is a  distributed across  let's say `cluster of machines` that let's you process really big data fast. For small volumes of data it won't be faster than any of R, python etc.

Comment: It is fast in its class. It means a type of tasks, type of resources (commodity hardware) and specific guarantees (like fault tolerance).

Answer (score 0):

The question is probably going to be closed, but anyway:

- Spark may or may not partition the job, to be more precise *the data*, depending on configuration. It's correct that partitioning helps the with the parallelism, which provides a major performance gain. This is either non-existent or very limited in Python libraries or R.
- A reasonably accurate explanation would be, spark is a cluster of processes which may or may not be on a single machine.

Comment: Can genetic algorithms be run faster on spark given that the search space is really big?